# Filling Listview with columns from database?

Tags: vb.net

I want to fill listview with column 0of table from database ,table name is selected from combobox,

```
 Dim ds As New DataSet()
 Dim ada As New SqlDataAdapter("Select COLUMN_NAME FROM  TABLE_NAME", con)
    MessageBox.Show(ComboBox1.SelectedText)
    ada.Fill(ds)
    Dim s As String = ""
    Dim lvi As ListViewItem = New ListViewItem()
    Dim myrow As DataRow
    For Each dt As DataTable In ds.Tables
        For Each myrow In dt.Rows
            Dim lv As New ListViewItem
            'lv.Text = myRow.Item(5)
            lv.SubItems.Add(myrow.Item(Convert.ToInt32(dt)))
            '   lv.SubItems.Add(myrow.Item(7))
            ListView1.Items.Add(lv)
        Next
    Next
    ' comboBox1.Items.Add(dt1);
    End Sub
```

Comment: I suppose TABLE_NAME should be a parameter if I understand correct what you are trying to achieve..Meaning COLUMN_NAME also

Comment: i am trying to load all tables name from my database to combobox and after selecting table name from combobox the column of selected table should be added into datagridview

Comment: so what is issue with your current code?

Comment: i want columns in vertical way, it display like scattered anywhere and i want to bound it with datagridview in above code i add column in listview

Comment: Is the list view's `View` property set to `Details`?